# Docker compose on cross-platform environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

Let's say I have a cross-platform environment,

my app is deployed twice - once on windows container and one on a Linux container,

In addition, I have a DB container (Linux).

Can I use docker compose to build those 3 services?

**I think not** - because the images I use are built for a certain os type.

Am I right? and maybe I am wrong and there is a workaround for this?

Comment: only using a `docker-compose` file it would not be possible, because you can't run images for Windows and Linux in the same machine, what could be possible of a solution is to use `docker-machine` to create a linux virtual machine, or something like that, but in any way, would you not be able to link then by docker or things like that... you would have to use a network outside docker to it

Comment: this post doesn't answer the question but should prove useful: https://blog.codeship.com/cross-platform-docker-development-environment/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Compose files using version 2.4 support the `platform` options, which allows for specifying the platform of the service.

```
platform: osx
platform: windows/amd64
platform: linux/arm64/v8
```

https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2.md#platform

It should be noted that the `platform` option is not supported on v3 compose files.

A more in-depth explanation can be found here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/mixing-windows-and-linux-containers-with-docker-compose/

Comment: Unfortunately, the platform-option is no longer part of docker-compose and the functionality is afaik only supported in the deprecated lcow docker-for-windows implementation.
As this topic is still under construction and the documentation is contradictory, please check the latest github issues on this.

Comment: It looks like buildx is the way to go now for building cross platfrom from docker-compose files.

`docker buildx bake --push --set *.platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563302/758542

Comment: platform option seems to be valid for me in the latest version. My problem is if I can define a variable (i.e in a file or environment) to take the value from there so every developer can set it's own value