# docker-compose multi arch

Tags: docker, docker-compose, multiarch

Docker images can be built for multi architectures. This is usually done by creating a specific image per architecture, and then creating manifest as a proxy to the right image depending on the system that pulls the image.

That's great.

Now, with `docker-compose`, it's also possible to build images, but I don't see a way to build the image depending on the architecture, so it seems like the only way to have a single docker-compose definition for multiple architectures, is to have pushed multi-arch images to a registry and pull from there.

Does anyone know of a way to build local images for the right arch with the docker-compose build step?

Answer (score 13):

I don't think you can use `docker-compose build`, but you could use `docker buildx bake` to build multi-arch using a `docker-compose.yml`.

```bash
docker buildx bake --push --set *.platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64
```

You'll probably want to read more about [docker buildx bake](https://github.com/docker/buildx#buildx-bake-options-target) and [building multi-platform images](https://github.com/docker/buildx#building-multi-platform-images).

Comment: That works great! A quick note, though at least on `zsh` (and I think on `bash` too), you need to _escape_ the _asterisk_ : `docker buildx bake --push --set "*.platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64"`

Answer (score 0):

Although the docker docs states, that [docker bake](https://docs.docker.com/build/bake/) is still experimental, it seems to work nicely along with [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and some bake-specific yaml keys.

Given the following simple `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  webapp:
    image: mycustom.registry/webapp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

You can express in the `docker-compose.yml` the *various* target architectures, by adding `x-bake` "stuff" (sorry, not so much into yaml lingo), that are read by `docker buildx bake`:

```
services:
  webapp:
    image: mycustom.registry/webapp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      x-bake:
        platforms:
          - linux/amd64
          - linux/arm64
```

and run `docker buildx bake` for *building* all *services* having a `build:` in the `docker-compose.yml` and `docker buildx bake --push` to *push* them, that will be build for `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64` respectively.

[That way you](https://docs.docker.com/build/bake/compose-file/#extension-field-with-x-bake) can leverage other features that docker bake offers, like [multiple tags](https://docs.docker.com/build/bake/reference/#targettags) *per build* or [build cache configuration](https://docs.docker.com/build/bake/reference/#targetcache-from).

This seems to be a functionally complete replacement of `docker compose build` (apart from docker compose specific *configuration merging* I guess) and `docker compose push`. [.env support](https://docs.docker.com/build/bake/compose-file/#env-file) seems to be equally available.